# Почему возникает ошибка при создании таблиц в бд?

Tags: laravel

Пытаюсь создать таблицы в бд, но возникает ошибка:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `posts` add constraint `posts_category_id_foreign` foreign key (`category_id`) references `categories` (`id`) on delete set null). Как это можно исправить?

```
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('published_by')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->string('slug', 50)->unique();
            $table->string('image', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('excerpt', 500)->nullable(false);
            $table->text('content')->nullable(false);
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->nullOnDelete();

            $table->foreign('published_by')->references('id')->on('users')->nullOnDelete();

            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->nullOnDelete();
        });
```

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('parant_id')->nullable(false)->default(0);
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->string('slug', 100)->unique();
            $table->string('image', 50)->nullable();
            $table->string('content', 500)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Проверьте, что у вас миграция с категориями запускается раньше, чем с постами.

Comment: А как это проверить?

Comment: Я разобрался, спасибо